# Start electron app with child_process.fork

Tags: node.js, electron, child-process

Is it possible to start an electron application from a node.js app with child_process.fork()?

I would like to take advantage of the IPC messaging the fork provides, but I cannot figure out how to start electron with only the modulePath instead 'electron .'.

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options

Answer (score 0):

I wound up using spawn instead and messaging with:

```
process.on('message', message => {
    console.log('message from parent: ', message);
  });
```

and

```
process.send('message to parent');
```